# The shape of my contact form doesn't change

Tags: joomla-3.x, helix3

I'm making a site using Joomla 3 + Helix Ultimate framework. I made a contact form which works flawlessly (using the default Joomla way to make the form), but there is a problem I haven't been able to fix: the form is shown like an accordion: there's a link, you click on it and it shows the form. What I want instead is to get rid of the accordion and show directly the form when you open the page. How can I achieve this? I even tried to change the option in the "view" tab (the one with options like "sliders, plain" etc), but nothing changed. Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you have some sort of Cache function enabled on your website like the settings in Global Configuration or the plugin 'System - Page Cache'? If you are not clearing the cache between changes then you may not see the change when you do things like change options from Slider,plain etc.

Comment: I've cleared the cache and checked the plugin, which is already disabled, and nothing changed. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

So, the way I fixed this issue is using CSS to target some class of the form generated by Joomla and change the display into "block". It's not an actual fix, but a workaround that works pretty well.